# how to create a directory with datestamp as its filename in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, timestamp, jenkins-pipeline, mkdirs, datestamp

```
bat 'set OutputFolderName=%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%'
bat 'mkdir %OutputFolderName%'
```

These two commands should give the correct output but they aren't working.
This is the error I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multiline bat command as follows:

```
bat """
    set OutputFolderName=%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
    mkdir %OutputFolderName%
"""
```

Edit: Updated with snapshots

Have a look at my pipeline snapshot here:
[image: Pipeline Snapshot]

Pipeline Console Output
[image: Pipeline Console Output]

Creates a folder something like this:

[image: Workspace Snapshot]

Comment: Nope Still not working...What's surprising is these commands work perfectly in a jenkinsjob but not in a pipeline script

Comment: I updated the answer with snapshot showing how the pipeline command I replaced with your command and it works.  Does your Jenkins Service or Agent has permission to created folders in the workspace??

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I made a mistake earlier in  multiline bat command...(kept 3 double quotes instead of 3 single quotes) I changed that and Now its working fine